# Approximation of cubic Bezier curve with arc

Tags: algorithm, svg, automatic-ref-counting, bezier, curve

As an input I have an SVG file where curves are defined under PATH element with:

- Two line commands: Move To (M) and Line (L)
- Curve command : Cubic Bezier curve (C)

I want to translate this into CAD system that can draw ARC and LINE elements.

Cubic Bezier curve is defined in following way:

C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y

Where:

x1 y1 is the first control point

x2 y2 is the second control point

x y is the end point

Start point is known.

The question is what would be the algorithm to translate cubic Bezier curve into an ARC? 
ARC can be drawn with specified centre/end/angle or start/end/through points.

Comment: What kind of "arc" is an `ARC`? Is it circular or e.g. a smooth interpolated curve which passes through specified points? A general cubic curve cannot be approximated with a single circular arc.

Comment: Yes its interpolated curve through specified points

Comment: maybe this one? https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arcapproximation

Comment: take a look at this: [Circular approximation of polygon (or its part)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251997/2521214)

Comment: It would appear this user isn't actually interested in getting their problem solved. Abandoned questions are the opposite of what makes Stackoverflow so useful.