# How to find circle center and radius if I only have circumference points of circle and circle is not at origin

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I have all the points on the circle circumference (x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...(xn, yn) but circle is not at origin.

So, is it possible to find the Circle center (X, Y) and Radius (R) from the given set of input points?

Please see the attached image.
[image: Circle_Center_and_radius_unknown]

Comment: What have you tried as algorithm up to now? For getting the center and the radius, 3 points are enough. If they give you 6, they probably want you to enhance the accuracy and you will have to work with averages.

Comment: see [Circular approximation of polygon (or its part)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251997/2521214) 3 points are enough for circle

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think now I got it how to formulate the equations from three points.